# node and soap service consumption

Tags: node.js, soap

Trying to make a SOAP call from Node. I have some schema name issues to make the service call successfully.

Here is what the existing SOAP expects as a request

REQUIRED

```
<soapenv:Body>
***<ser:MyServiceName> ***
    <ser:request>
       <ecms:serviceId>123456789</ecms:serviceId
       <ecms:TransactionID>TestTransId</ecms:TransactionID>
    </ser:request>
   </ser:MyServiceName>
</soapenv:Body>
```

and here is my request looks like

WHAT I HAVE NOW

```
    <soap:Body>
   ***<xsns:MyServiceName xmlns:xsns="http://example.com/ecms/services"        xmlns="http://example.com/ecms/services">***
     <ser:request>
        <ecms:serviceId>123456789</ecms:serviceId>
        <ecms:TransactionID>TestTransId</ecms:TransactionID>
      </ser:request>
   </xsns:MyServiceName>
 </soap:Body>
```

My question would be how to edit/correct the element

'

```
    "<xsns:MyServiceName xmlns:xsns="http://example.com/ecms/services"        xmlns="http://example.com/ecms/services">"
```

to

```
    <ser:MyServiceName>
```

as shown in the expected SOAP request above.

Here is the code I have

```
    var args = {"ser:request":{"ecms:serviceId”:”123456789”,   "ecms:TransactionID":"TestTransId"}};
    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

      client.MyServiceName(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeaders) {
        console.log('LAST REQUEST ');
        console.log(client.lastRequest);
        console.log(result);
      });
     });
```

I am sure this is something to do with the options but I am not able to figure out. 
I tried using options like this but it did not solve the problem.

```
     var options = {
              ignoredNamespaces: true
            };
```

Anythoughts, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

And here is how wsdl for this service looks

```
    <wsdl:message name="IServiceRequest_MyServiceName_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:xsns="http://example.com/ecms/services"   name="parameters" element="xsns:MyServiceName"/>
    </wsdl:message>
```